# Best way to store the day of the week using NSDate and NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I'm trying to reproduce some of the functionality of the default Clock where I let users select a repeat frequency for an alarm.  The problem is that different NSCalendar settings will give you different names for the days of the week.  How do I store the selected days of the week in such a way that if the user changes their calendar the frequency always falls on the right day of the week?

Comment: Assuming that you're sticking with the 7-day Gregorian calendar, just store the numeric value for the day of the week.

Comment: @HotLicks the problem is that I can't stick with one calendar.  I can't reliably predict what settings people are going to have.

Comment: If you can't even assume a Gregorian calendar (ie, you don't even know if it's a 7-day week), I don't know how you can expect to store a selected day of the week.

Comment: @HotLicks so is there no way to convert between Gregorian, Chinese, Hebrew, and Islamic calendars?  (the calendars supported by iOS)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to check if the calendar has changed every time the app comes into foreground, and if so, make appropriate changes from there. Probably not the most elegant solution, nor the best practice, but it could get the job done.

Answer (score -2):

Take `(long) [dateYouWantToRemember timeIntervalSince1970]` and store that in a property file or some such.  (You could use timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, but the 1970 number is the "UNIX epoch date" and more standardized -- you can find converters online to check it.)

Later, under the (potentially) different calendar, do `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:theLongYouStored]` and you will reconstruct the date, in the new calendar.

Now use NSCalendar/NSDateComponents to find out the new ordinal day of week of that date, and use `[NSDateFormatter weekdaySymbols]` to fetch a list of the weekday names.  Index the list with the ordinal to fetch the new day name.  Use NSDateComponents to do arithmetic on you dates to select the next date that is that day of the week, as needed for your app.

Comment: (To future readers: This answer was just downvoted out of spite and the said downvote is not a reflection of the excellent advice contained in the answer.)